# How to convert nested parent child hierarchy json to pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, loops

I have a parent df:

```
id  parentTerm isLeaf  children
0     A          F     [{'_id': 'A1', 'parentTerm': 'B', 'isLeaf': F, 'children': [{'_id': 'A11', 'parentTerm': 'B', 'isLeaf': T, 'children':[]}]}]
```

The number of children inside children column differs for other parentdf dataframes,

I want to loop inside every dictionary inside  parent df.children and get it appended to a dataframe. Not sure how to write a loop that passes through any number of dictionaries.

I tried pd.json_normalize but since the children is in the list of dictionary, it does not return the flattend output.

Desired Output:

```
id    parentTerm isLeaf 
0        A         F    
A1       B         F
A11      B         T
```

Please help.

I tried the below code and it works:

```
def test_iterate(parent_df):
    global total_data
    total_data = total_data.append(parent_df[['_id', 'parentTerm','isLeaf']])
     try:
        parent_df['children'].apply(lambda x:test_iterate(pd.DataFrame(x)))
     except Exception as inst:
    #print(inst)
        pass
total_data = pd.DataFrame()
test_iterate(parent_df)
```

But I am invoking the function inside aws lambda and it doesn't recognize the global variable.

Comment: Can you demonstrate *any* effort at solving this yourself?

Comment: Please include your *formatted* code in the question.

Comment: Hoping for a solution

Comment: How do you square "code and it works" with "doesn't recognize the global variable"?

Answer (score 0):

Pass `total_data` as a parameter to `test_iterate`.

Comment: Tried, that again return only the parent_df values but does not parses through nested dictionary.